# Using a factory in config

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-factory, angularjs-provider, angularjs-config

I know the config phase runs before the services are available, but I have a situation where I need to use a `myJsonDateTimeService` to inject a `$httpProvider.defaults.transformResponse` like that:

```
angular.module('myJsonDateTimeInterceptor', ['myJsonDateTime'])
.config(function($httpProvider, myJsonDateTimeService){
    $httpProvider.defaults.transformResponse.push(function(responseData){
        myJsonDateTime.format(responseData); // Logic to change DateTime.
        return responseData;
    });
});

angular.module('myJsonDateTime', [])
.factory('myJsonDateTimeService', function(){
    var factory = {
        format: function(data) { ... }
    };
    return factory;    
});
```

The problem is that `myJsonDateTimeService` is used as service in other places and I would like to reuse the same logic in the config of my interceptor instead just replicate the format code.

I also don't know how to create a `myJsonDateTimeProvider` that could use the same logic of the factory.

**Edit 1**

As suggested, I rebuild this factory in a provider like that:

```
angular.module('myJsonDateTime', [])
.provider('myJsonDateTimeService', function(){
    var format = function(data) { ... };
    this.format = format;

    this.$get = function() {
        return { format: format };
    };
});
```

Not sure if that's the best way as the provider should be used to configure and not provide functions like formatting.

Comment: factory can't be injected inside config, factory should be re-written as `provider` which will be configurable `factory`, look at [this for details](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28262966/2435473)